Best way to get random photo from camera roll without loading all of them?
I've been trying a long time to get this working, but no luck. I just want to pull 1 random image from my phone/emulator's camera roll. The issue is that RN and all packages that I've found have to load every image in order, and then randomly choose. This takes forever if you have a large camera roll. Is there a way to just get a list of photo ids and choose from that?
